# Why do I need to import React from 'react' in the index.js file when it's not neccessary to import react anymore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

> I am learning React.js. I saw that after version 17 it's no longer needed to import React anymore. My currrent react version is v18.2.0. I am using this code:

```
// import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

> I am getting this error:

*Failed to compile.*

*[eslint]
src\index.js
Line 8:4:  'React' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef*

*Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
ERROR in [eslint]
src\index.js*
*Line 8:4:  'React' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef*

*Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.*

*webpack compiled with 1 error*

Do I have to import React from 'react'? What can I do to avoid this error?

I have commented out the `import React from 'react';` line and I am getting the error mention above.

I expect my code to compile successfully..

Comment: Hi. As I understand (https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html ) this, we have to transform JSX into regular java Script (https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html). Otherwise browser cannot understand our JSX code. In the previous one this link mention about the transformation (https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html). It use "React.createElement(...)" under the hood. But in the new version the introduce new transform function. It wans mention in that previous link.

Comment: "To solve these issues, React 17 introduces two new entry points to the React package that are intended to only be used by compilers like Babel and TypeScript. Instead of transforming JSX to React.createElement, the new JSX transform automatically imports special functions from those new entry points in the React package and calls them"  (https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#whats-different-in-the-new-transform)

Comment: import {jsx as _jsx} from 'react/jsx-runtime'; this is the new function used for this transformation instead of the ""React.createElement(...)".  As I understand this that's why we don't want to use that React import for create new Element. But in the index.json file we use "React.StrictMode". to use this we have to import this. As, I understand this, this is the reason. I It's better to read bit more about this yourself. Because I also not a expert of a react. Just want to give something for you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply this error comes from eslint not react as of react 17, jsx transformation has changed.

In you eslint config file, place turn these off:

```
"react/jsx-uses-react": "off",
"react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
```

This should clear the error